# Error al insertar una fecha formateada

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando insertar una fecha en oracle desde visual studio.
La variable de mi comando queda así:

```
INSERT INTO Atiende(atiFechaAtencion, cliNit, pacId) 
VALUES (to_date('26/01/2019 7:05:31 a. m.',dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi),1,1)
```

pero no inserta y da el error:

> date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Creo que te faltan unas comillas alrededor del formato.

Comment: Adicional el string de la fecha difiere al formato que estas especificando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [función TO_DATE en Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) toma hasta tres parámetros: la cadena a transformar y opcionalmente la máscara de formato y el idioma. Todos esos parámetros son cadenas en sí, por lo que deben ir entrecomillados.

Además, el formato de la cadena debe seguir el formato especificado en la máscara. La cadena tiene este formato `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS A.M.` pero tu máscara es `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi`. Deberías actualizarla para que sean iguales.

Con esos cambios, el código quedaría así:

```
INSERT INTO Atiende(atiFechaAtencion, cliNit, pacId) 
VALUES (to_date('26/01/2019 7:05:31 a.m.', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS A.M.'),1,1)
```

> Nota: no he probado la consulta porque no tengo Oracle y puede contener algún fallo. Espero que el enlace de arriba y [este otro](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) puedan servirte de referencia.

Comment: El string de la fecha difiere al formato que estas especificando

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa es cierto, gracias por indicarlo. Voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: El `a. m.` es sin espacio, con esa correccion debe de funcionar perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo :)