# Formatear new Date();

Tags: javascript, sql, date

Estoy teniendo un problema con el tema de formatear fechas en JavaScript.

Lo primero que hago es declarar una variable para guardar la fecha de tipo Date:

```
var fecha = new Date("2020-04-26T00:00:00");
```

Esto me devuelve la fecha en este formato:

> Sun Apr 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)

El problema es que yo necesito que esa fecha esté en el siguiente formato:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

Y seguía siendo un tipo Date, intenté formatear pero me devolvía un tipo String que no me sirve. Esto lo necesito por que en la base de datos Oracle para este campo solo acepta un Date.

Comment: El date solo existe en el navegador, cuando envíes la fecha al servidor se convertirá en un string.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al insertar una fecha formateada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248878/error-al-insertar-una-fecha-formateada)